# How to create a custom Dask worker with imports

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I'm setting up Dask, and I can use dask for multiprocessing just fine.

I run into issues, however, when I want to use pre-configured Dask workers. They don't have the same imports I do with my main process.

I was wondering. How do I add custom imports into dask workers so all futures accessing those workers can operate effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you Dask workers should all have the same software environment.  Typically this is guaranteed outside of Dask with Docker images or with a Network File System (NFS).  There are some other solutions like `Client.upload_file`, which can be useful for small scripts.